# Error while importing: 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'

Tags: reactjs, import, importerror, codemirror, react-codemirror

Code:

```
import React from 'react'

import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';

export default function Editor() {

  return (

    <div>Editor</div>

  )

}
```

Error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'
```

Please provide a solution for this error..

Comment: It's not clear what issue you're running into - does `codemirror/lib/codemirror.css` exist? Does it need to be imported from a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

First, run:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

After that try to run

```
npm i codemirror@version5
```

then restart the vs-code